# How to fine from where in UVM factory class been overrided

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

In our model one class been overrided inside UVM factory, how i can find where this done?
I am using vcs DVE / VERDI for debugging.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
// variable to store a reference to the factory
uvm_factory factory;

// get a reference to the factory
factory = uvm_factory::get();

// print the contents of the factory
factory.print();
```

Or all in one line:

```
uvm_factory::get().print();
```